# Make sendmail listen to external ip

Tags: sendmail

How can I made sendmail on FreeBSD listen to port 25 outside of the system, so I can receive mail from outside services.  Currently it is only able to receive mail locally though it can send mail fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verify that you have `sendmail_enable=YES` in your /etc/rc.conf file (and then of course restart sendmail).  This will tell sendmail to listen to something other than just your loopback adapter.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set up port forwarding on your firewall or router to forward SMTP traffic from the public ip address of the router to the private ip address of the server.